# Setting the profile level for libx265 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.265

I'm trying to set the profile level of libx265 to mainstillpicture using ffmpeg. But I can't seem to do so.  I'm basically trying to encode every frame as intra  frame (only spatial encoding) with no temporal encoding.

I've tried the following commands

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 3840x2160 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i <input_filename> -c:v libx265 -b:v 45000k -preset veryslow -profile:v mainstillpicture <output_filename>
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 3840x2160 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i <input_filename> -c:v libx265 -b:v 45000k -preset veryslow -profile:v 3 <output_filename>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I don't know about setting the profile with ffmpeg, this is the x265 CLI code when setting the profile to main still picture :

```
param->maxNumReferences = 1;

/* The bitstream shall contain only one picture (we do not enforce this) */
/* just in case the user gives us more than one picture: */
param->keyframeMax = 1;
param->bOpenGOP = 0;
param->bRepeatHeaders = 1;
param->lookaheadDepth = 0;
param->bframes = 0;
param->scenecutThreshold = 0;
param->bFrameAdaptive = 0;
param->rc.cuTree = 0;
param->bEnableWeightedPred = 0;
param->bEnableWeightedBiPred = 0
```

So you can probably do something like this :

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 3840x2160 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i <input_filename> -c:v libx265 -b:v 45000k -preset veryslow -x265-params keyint=1:ref=1:no-open-gop=1:weightp=0:weightb=0:cutree=0:rc-lookahead=0:bframes=0:scenecut=0:b-adapt=0:repeat-headers=1 <output_filename>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. Where did you find the CLI code for the main still picture? Would be great if I could try other profiles.

Comment: It was changed recently, you can find it here : https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/commits/86e4612d4c9c6980bede235f37bda72053cd51d5#Lsource/encoder/encoder.cppT1392 . However there aren't really "other profiles" apart from Main and Main10..

Answer (score 0):

> If `--total-frames` is 1, then a stillpicture variant will be signaled,
>   but this parameter is not always set by applications,
>   particularly not when the CLI uses stdin streaming
>   or when libx265 is used by third-party applications.

From [Command Line Options — x265 documentation](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/cli.html#profile-level-tier).

So set option `-x265-params total-frames=1`.